# What is Webgl ? How it work on it?

Tags: webgl

What is Webgl and How to make something in it ?
I have given an assignment to make rotating globe in Webgl but I donot know that what it is and how to work on it, I only know how to code this in HTML. What should I do ? please help.

Comment: This question doesn't show the least bit of research effort. Please read up on WebGL yourself and [edit] your question once you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 7):

WebGL is a branch of OpenGL based on OpenGL Embedded Systems (ES).  It is run in browsers through a `<canvas>` element after getting a context from said element.  All calls are done through JavaScript. You can find a ton of tutorials through google.  One that I used a lot when I was starting can be found here: [Mozilla WebGL Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL)

Additionally, WebGL is still growing and while most modern browsers support it, you may need to enable it.  There are also some features or caveats between implimentations.  For example, Internet Explorer 11 supports WebGL but I found that you cannot use `structs` in your GLSL yet, a feature that Chrome and Firefox both support.  To find out if you can run WebGL, either go to a demo page such as the one found here: [Chrome Experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl/) or just go here: [Get WebGL](http://get.webgl.org/)

Comment: does WebGL code run on GPU?

Answer (score 1):

WebGL is a JavaScript library for drawing 3D graphics (based on the OpenGL ES 2.0 API) in a web browser inside of an HTML5 canvas element.  Using it will require some knowledge of writing OpenGL vertex and fragment shaders, and computer graphics in general.

There are many sites on the internet that contain samples (very likely for precisely what you've been asked to do). However, if you want to learn, there are some simple examples at [Ed Angel's web site](http://www.unm.edu/~angel).

Comment: does WebGL code run on GPU?

Comment: @Lakshay Yes.  The JavaScript application runs in the browser on the device, and uses the local graphics hardware (assuming one exists; it's likely that WebGL would not initialize if there isn't hardware).  In most (if not all) implementations, when a WebGL call is executed by the JavaScript engine, it's translated into a "native" graphics API (e.g., DirectX, OpenGL, OpenGL ES, etc.), which talks to the local hardware.